# ogre3d material by default?

Tags: ogre3d, ogre

I've seen that when you add some models to the *scene_manager* their texture is there by default, you don't need to set the *setMaterialName*. How is this? Is it in the mesh or some material name that auto assigns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the material name is set in the .mesh file when you export the model.